# Call Spring batch jobs on remote server

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I use Spring Batch Admin to manage and monitor jobs and executions. How can I call a job and launch it from a standalone java application with given HTTP Connection to the server containing Spring Batch Admin WebAPP.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring Batch Admin JSON API](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/reference/json.html) to do so - it is possible to list jobs as well as to run them. Additionally, you can expose [JMX beans](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/reference/jmx.html#Monitoring_and_Management_with_JMX) to monitor and manage batch jobs remotely.

Below is an example of json POST request to the job service launching job named 'job1':

```
$ curl -d jobParameters=fail=false http://localhost:8080/spring-batch-admin-sample/batch/jobs/job1.json
{"jobExecution" : { 
    "resource" : "http://localhost:8080/spring-batch-admin-sample/batch/jobs/executions/2.json",
    "id" : "2",
    "status" : "STARTING",
    "startTime" : "",
    "duration" : "",
    "exitCode" : "UNKNOWN",
    "exitDescription" : "",
    "jobInstance" : { "resource" : "http://localhost:8080/spring-batch-admin-sample/batch/jobs/job1/1.json" },
    "stepExecutions" : {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First thank you for your reply.
I read about JSON API and I know how to list jobs on server but I did not see how to run a given job. please just give me steps to do it

Comment: It's hard to give exact answer, because it depends on the nature of your job. I've updated the answer giving an example of request launching 'job1'.

Answer (score 1):

you can use simply HttpURLConnection with the JOB url and its parameter.

the URL construct would be like 
"http://:8080/spring-batch-admin-sample/batch/jobs/yourJob?jobParameters=" + URLEncoder.encode("param1=value,param2=value2", UTF-8)

let me know, for any clarifications.....